# Dynamicaly changing behavior of mocks in Mockito

Tags: java, testing, mockito

Hello I would like to know, if there is any way to dynamicaly modify behaviour of mocks in Mockito.

For example I have a method count() and I would like Mockito to return a value higher by one every time I call it on mock.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes... Create an [Answer](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.5/javadoc/org/mockito/stubbing/Answer.html) and stub it out on your mock using doAnswer().

Comment: Hey, your lnk is dead.

Comment: @Traendy yes it is. This answer linking to a specific class in Mockito’s Javadoc at the time was posted 9 years ago. I haven’t done serious Java development in about 6 years, and Google code shut down 4 years ago. But that’s why Stack Overflow is editable. Instead of just complaining about a lack of instant gratification, you can search for what the current link should be, and with enough rep update the answer. Or comment with the new link. Or if there have been breaking changes in 9 years, post your own answer with an updated method and thus improve the collective body of work. Good luck!

Comment: Some quick searching it looks like https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.3.3/org/mockito/stubbing/Answer.html might be the same interface in the current version. But the URL posted 9 years ago was version 1.5 and this is 2 major versions later (3.3.3) so leaving this in a comment as your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 4):

Of course, for your count()-method getting an increment the Mockito-Answer is the best way.

BTW: But nevertheless remind that you can 'change' (define) the behaviour of a mocked-method in case of subsequent invocations:

```
when(mock.someMethod("some arg"))
.thenThrow(new RuntimeException())
.thenReturn("foo");
```

Here you see first invocation throws a RuntimeException, the second invocation returns the String "foo" ...